# After Joomla update duplicate or create new module get id : 0

Tags: module, sql

Joomla is updated to 3.3 and create of a new module or duplicate existing module with no success.

Its possible to create a new, or duplicate modules but module id is 0 for each new module I create, so its not editable after saving you cant go to edit page because id is 0.

Any suggests before you suggest to update it again.

I get this error with template Hathor :

```
Error

Duplicate entry '0-101' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO zm_modules_menu (moduleid,menuid) VALUES (0,101)
```

another backend template show no error but same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Check your data base xxx_module must assign AUTO_INCREMENT STATUS, after it will be ok!

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone to your PHP my admin and manually adjusting the IDs in the module table and then tried duplicating a module? I would start there, export the sql file with the modules, do a quick search and replace.

Then delete the existing modules, reimport the updated sql file.  Try to duplicate a module and then see what happens.

Comment: With backup of sql i can create and dublicate but problem is have made many changes so icant use that backup ( only backup of 4 mnt old works others not)

Comment: Did you try adjusting the auto increment keys?